# How to regexp_replace based on another regexp_replace?

Tags: sql, oracle

In table(oracle sql) i have such string

```
TEXT                                     | PARAMS
random text [[aaa]], random text [[n]]*n | aaa=1,bbb=7,n=n*n
```

Can i replace all [[ ]] from 'TEXT' with 'PARAMS'?
If it's possible i think it will be like:

```
select regexp_replace('[[aaa]]', '[[.*]]', regexp_substr('aaa=1', '\1')) from dual;
```

can anybody explain how i should do it without PLSQL?

Comment: Yes, but how can you know how many nested replacements to make?  You probably can't.  But doing this in Java or a similar tool would be fairly straightforward.  I would rather do this type of data scrubbing outside of the database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes i dont know how many nested replacements, so i asked here how to do it. Yeah, i know 1001 way how to do it on php/java/python, but in this case i should use ONLY SQL. It's not my choice :)

Comment: Upvoted to help you get an answer +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `REPLACE`, `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` functions - if you use regular expressions then you will also need to escape characters in the replacement parameter that have special meaning in regular expressions.

**Sample data**:

```
CREATE TABLE inputs ( text, params ) AS
  SELECT 'random text [[aaa]], random text [[n]]*n', 'aaa=1,bbb=7,n=n*n' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH replacement ( text, params, idx ) AS (
  SELECT REPLACE(
           text,
           '[[' || SUBSTR( params, 1, INSTR( params, '=', 1 ) - 1 ) || ']]',
           CASE INSTR( params, ',', 1 )
             WHEN 0
             THEN SUBSTR( params, INSTR( params, '=', 1 ) + 1 )
             ELSE SUBSTR( params, INSTR( params, '=', 1 ) + 1, INSTR( params, ',', 1 ) - INSTR( params, '=', 1 ) - 1 )
           END
         ),
         params,
         INSTR( params, ',', 1 ) + 1
  FROM   inputs
UNION ALL
  SELECT REPLACE(
           text,
           '[[' || SUBSTR( params, idx, INSTR( params, '=', idx ) - idx ) || ']]',
           CASE INSTR( params, ',', idx )
             WHEN 0
             THEN SUBSTR( params, INSTR( params, '=', idx ) + 1 )
             ELSE SUBSTR( params, INSTR( params, '=', idx ) + 1, INSTR( params, ',', idx ) - INSTR( params, '=', idx ) - 1 )
           END
         ),
         params,
         INSTR( params, ',', idx ) + 1
  FROM   replacement
  WHERE  idx > 1
)
SELECT text
FROM   replacement
WHERE  idx = 1;
```

**Output**

```
TEXT
--------------------------------
random text 1, random text n*n*n
```

Comment: great thnx! :-)

Comment: ,i have another similar case, but params in another table: CREATE TABLE inputs ( text ) AS
  SELECT 'random text <<<aaa>>> blablabla <<<bbb>>>' FROM DUAL;
  
  CREATE TABLE params ( name, value ) AS
  SELECT 'aaa', 'qqq' FROM DUAL
  union all
  SELECT 'bbb', 'www' FROM DUAL
  ; /// can u show how it will be in this case?

Comment: @newSqlz You would do better asking that as a new question as the answer will be sufficiently different to this one to create confusion in a single answer.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/45864868/